# Qt ogre3d application - error loading scripts and materials

Tags: c++, qt, ogre

I am using Qt5 and Ogre3D 1.9 and I aim to have at the end an ogreWidget working on my machine. But first, I am trying to create a simple ogre app. (I am working with windows7)

Therefore, I followed this tutorial:  [Setting Up An Application With QtCreator](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting%20Up%20An%20Application%20-%20QtCreator)

I runned into several problems: First I can only load the openGL render system, see the plugin file and the dlls below.

I can compile, but cannot load the resources scripts and materials for the basic example. This example is an app showing the Ogre head. Thus, without these resources, the head has no texture...

Thus, here are my questions:
- how can I get the example to work with textures, and is the texture problem really dependent on the two resources I cannot load? 
- should I use an older version of either Qt or Ogre3D?
- At the end, my goal is to have a qtwidget working, does anyone have some clue for this too?

Thanks for your time.

**The dlls:**

cg, ogremain_d, OgreOverlay_d, OgrePaging_d, OgreProperty_d, OgreRTSshaderSystem_d, OgreTerrain_d,OgreVolume_d, OIS_d, Plugin_CgProgramManager_d, PluginBSPSceneManager_d, PluginOctreeSceneManager_d,OctreeZone_d, Plugin_ParticleFX_d,PluginPCZSceneManager_d,RenderSystem_Direct3D9_d,RenderSystem_Direct3D11_d,RenderSystem_GL_d.

**The plugin File**

```
# Define plugin folder
PluginFolder=.

# Define plugins
# Plugin=RenderSystem_Direct3D9_d
# Plugin=RenderSystem_Direct3D11_d
 Plugin=RenderSystem_GL_d
# Plugin=RenderSystem_GL3Plus_d
# Plugin=RenderSystem_GLES_d
# Plugin=RenderSystem_GLES2_d
 Plugin=Plugin_ParticleFX_d
 Plugin=Plugin_BSPSceneManager_d
 Plugin=Plugin_CgProgramManager_d
# Plugin=Plugin_PCZSceneManager_d
# Plugin=Plugin_OctreeZone_d
 Plugin=Plugin_OctreeSceneManager_d
```

**The resource file:**

```
[Essential]
Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/packs/SdkTrays.zip
Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/packs/profiler.zip
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/thumbnails

# Common sample resources needed by many of the samples.
# Rarely used resources should be separately loaded by the
# samples which require them.
[Popular]
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/materials/textures
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/materials/textures/nvidia
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/models
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/DeferredShadingMedia
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/fonts
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/materials/programs
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/PCZAppMedia
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/RTShaderLib
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/materials/scripts/SSAO
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/materials/textures/SSAO
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/volumeTerrain
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/particle
# beneath files causing problems with DualQuaternions_Common.glsl
#FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/materials/scripts
#FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/RTShaderLib/materials

Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/packs/cubemap.zip
Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/packs/cubemapsJS.zip
Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/packs/dragon.zip
Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/packs/fresneldemo.zip
Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/packs/ogretestmap.zip
Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/packs/ogredance.zip
Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/packs/Sinbad.zip
Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/packs/skybox.zip
Zip=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media/volumeTerrain/volumeTerrainBig.zip

[General]
FileSystem=C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/media
```

**The .pro File:**

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = Ogre01

DEFINES -= UNICODE

#CONFIG -= qt

unix {
    # You may need to change this include directory
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/OGRE
    CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
    PKGCONFIG += OGRE
}
win32 {
    LIBS *= user32.lib
    LIBS += -LC:\\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0\\boost\\lib
    release:LIBS += -LC:\\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0\\lib\\release
    debug:LIBS += -LC:\\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0\\lib\\debug
    INCLUDEPATH += C:\\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0\\include
    INCLUDEPATH += C:\\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0\\include\\OIS
    INCLUDEPATH += C:\\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0\\include\\OGRE
    INCLUDEPATH += C:\\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0\\boost
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0/include/OGRE/Overlay
}
INCLUDEPATH += include

debug {
    TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,d)
    LIBS *= -lOgreMain_d -lOIS_d -lOgreOverlay_d
}
release:LIBS *= -lOgreMain -lOIS -lOgreOverlay

HEADERS += \
    include/Ogre01.h \
    include/BaseApplication.h \
    #include/myapp.h \
    include/BaseApplication.h

SOURCES += \
    src/Ogre01.cpp \
    src/BaseApplication.cpp \
    #src/myapp.cpp \
    src/BaseApplication.cpp
```

I add below the Ogre.log file I get when I try to load the two resources scripts and materials:

```
...

11:35:32: ***************************
11:35:32: *** GL Renderer Started ***
11:35:32: ***************************
11:35:32: Registering ResourceManager for type GpuProgram
11:35:32: GLSL support detected
11:35:32: GL: Using GL_EXT_framebuffer_object for rendering to textures (best)
11:35:32: FBO PF_UNKNOWN depth/stencil support: D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:32: FBO PF_L8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:32: FBO PF_A8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_A4L4 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_BYTE_LA depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_R5G6B5 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_B5G6R5 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_A4R4G4B4 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_A1R5G5B5 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_R8G8B8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_B8G8R8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_A8R8G8B8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_B8G8R8A8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_A2R10G10B10 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_A2B10G10R10 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_FLOAT16_RGB depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_FLOAT16_RGBA depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_FLOAT32_RGB depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_FLOAT32_RGBA depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_X8R8G8B8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_X8B8G8R8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_SHORT_RGBA depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_R3G3B2 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_FLOAT16_R depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_FLOAT32_R depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_FLOAT16_GR depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_FLOAT32_GR depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: FBO PF_SHORT_RGB depth/stencil support: D0S0 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
11:35:33: [GL] : Valid FBO targets PF_UNKNOWN PF_L8 PF_A8 PF_A4L4 PF_BYTE_LA PF_R5G6B5 PF_B5G6R5 PF_A4R4G4B4 PF_A1R5G5B5 PF_R8G8B8 PF_B8G8R8 PF_A8R8G8B8 PF_B8G8R8A8 PF_A2R10G10B10 PF_A2B10G10R10 PF_FLOAT16_RGB PF_FLOAT16_RGBA PF_FLOAT32_RGB PF_FLOAT32_RGBA PF_X8R8G8B8 PF_X8B8G8R8 PF_SHORT_RGBA PF_R3G3B2 PF_FLOAT16_R PF_FLOAT32_R PF_FLOAT16_GR PF_FLOAT32_GR PF_SHORT_RGB 
11:35:33: RenderSystem capabilities
11:35:33: -------------------------
11:35:33: RenderSystem Name: OpenGL Rendering Subsystem
11:35:33: GPU Vendor: nvidia
11:35:33: Device Name: Quadro 4000/PCIe/SSE2
11:35:33: Driver Version: 4.2.0.0
11:35:33:  * Fixed function pipeline: yes
11:35:33:  * Hardware generation of mipmaps: yes
11:35:33:  * Texture blending: yes
11:35:33:  * Anisotropic texture filtering: yes
11:35:33:  * Dot product texture operation: yes
11:35:33:  * Cube mapping: yes
11:35:33:  * Hardware stencil buffer: yes
11:35:33:    - Stencil depth: 8
11:35:33:    - Two sided stencil support: yes
11:35:33:    - Wrap stencil values: yes
11:35:33:  * Hardware vertex / index buffers: yes
11:35:33:  * Vertex programs: yes
11:35:33:  * Number of floating-point constants for vertex programs: 1024
11:35:33:  * Number of integer constants for vertex programs: 0
11:35:33:  * Number of boolean constants for vertex programs: 0
11:35:33:  * Fragment programs: yes
11:35:33:  * Number of floating-point constants for fragment programs: 512
11:35:33:  * Number of integer constants for fragment programs: 0
11:35:33:  * Number of boolean constants for fragment programs: 0
11:35:33:  * Geometry programs: yes
11:35:33:  * Number of floating-point constants for geometry programs: 2048
11:35:33:  * Number of integer constants for geometry programs: 0
11:35:33:  * Number of boolean constants for geometry programs: 0
11:35:33:  * Tesselation Hull programs: no
11:35:33:  * Number of floating-point constants for tesselation hull programs: 0
11:35:33:  * Number of integer constants for tesselation hull programs: 0
11:35:33:  * Number of boolean constants for tesselation hull programs: 15
11:35:33:  * Tesselation Domain programs: no
11:35:33:  * Number of floating-point constants for tesselation domain programs: 0
11:35:33:  * Number of integer constants for tesselation domain programs: 29793
11:35:33:  * Number of boolean constants for tesselation domain programs: 29285
11:35:33:  * Compute programs: no
11:35:33:  * Number of floating-point constants for compute programs: 24937
11:35:33:  * Number of integer constants for compute programs: 108
11:35:33:  * Number of boolean constants for compute programs: 0
11:35:33:  * Supported Shader Profiles: arbfp1 arbvp1 fp20 fp30 fp40 glsl gp4fp gp4gp gp4vp gpu_fp gpu_gp gpu_vp nvgp4 vp30 vp40
11:35:33:  * Texture Compression: yes
11:35:33:    - DXT: yes
11:35:33:    - VTC: yes
11:35:33:    - PVRTC: no
11:35:33:    - ATC: no
11:35:33:    - ETC1: no
11:35:33:    - ETC2: no
11:35:33:    - BC4/BC5: no
11:35:33:    - BC6H/BC7: no
11:35:33:  * Scissor Rectangle: yes
11:35:33:  * Hardware Occlusion Query: yes
11:35:33:  * User clip planes: yes
11:35:33:  * VET_UBYTE4 vertex element type: yes
11:35:33:  * Infinite far plane projection: yes
11:35:33:  * Hardware render-to-texture: yes
11:35:33:  * Floating point textures: yes
11:35:33:  * Non-power-of-two textures: yes
11:35:33:  * 1d textures: yes
11:35:33:  * Volume textures: yes
11:35:33:  * Multiple Render Targets: 8
11:35:33:    - With different bit depths: yes
11:35:33:  * Point Sprites: yes
11:35:33:  * Extended point parameters: yes
11:35:33:  * Max Point Size: 63.375
11:35:33:  * Vertex texture fetch: yes
11:35:33:  * Number of world matrices: 0
11:35:33:  * Number of texture units: 16
11:35:33:  * Stencil buffer depth: 8
11:35:33:  * Number of vertex blend matrices: 0
11:35:33:    - Max vertex textures: 32
11:35:33:    - Vertex textures shared: yes
11:35:33:  * Render to Vertex Buffer : yes
11:35:33:  * Hardware Atomic Counters: no
11:35:33:  * GL 1.5 without VBO workaround: no
11:35:33:  * Frame Buffer objects: yes
11:35:33:  * Frame Buffer objects (ARB extension): no
11:35:33:  * Frame Buffer objects (ATI extension): no
11:35:33:  * PBuffer support: yes
11:35:33:  * GL 1.5 without HW-occlusion workaround: no
11:35:33:  * Vertex Array Objects: no
11:35:33:  * Separate shader objects: no
11:35:33: DefaultWorkQueue('Root') initialising on thread efc.
11:35:33: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread 1354 starting.
11:35:33: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread 92c starting.
11:35:33: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread 288 starting.
11:35:33: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread de8 starting.
11:35:33: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread fb0 starting.
11:35:33: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread e20 starting.
11:35:33: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread 244 starting.
11:35:33: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread 9fc starting.
11:35:33: Particle Renderer Type 'billboard' registered
11:35:33: SceneManagerFactory for type 'BspSceneManager' registered.
11:35:33: Registering ResourceManager for type BspLevel
11:35:33: SceneManagerFactory for type 'OctreeSceneManager' registered.
11:35:33: OverlayElementFactory for type Panel registered.
11:35:33: OverlayElementFactory for type BorderPanel registered.
11:35:33: OverlayElementFactory for type TextArea registered.
11:35:33: Registering ResourceManager for type Font
11:35:33: Parsing scripts for resource group Autodetect
11:35:33: Finished parsing scripts for resource group Autodetect
11:35:33: Creating resources for group Autodetect
11:35:33: All done
11:35:33: Parsing scripts for resource group Essential
11:35:33: Parsing script SdkTrays.material
11:35:33: Parsing script OgreProfiler.material
11:35:33: Parsing script SdkTrays.fontdef
11:35:33: Parsing script SdkTrays.overlay
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_cursor.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_tray.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,64x64x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,64x64x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_button_up.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,128x32x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,128x32x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_text_box.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_mini_tray.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_track.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,16x32x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,16x32x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_handle.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,16x16x1) with 4 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,16x16x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_mini_text_box.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_label.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_separator.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,64x16x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,64x16x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_logo.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,128x64x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,128x64x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_shade.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,64x48x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,64x48x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_frame.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_mini_text_box_over.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1) with 5 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,32x32x1.
11:35:33: Texture: sdk_pulse.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_R8G8B8,8x1x1) with 3 hardware generated mipmaps from Image. Internal format is PF_X8R8G8B8,8x1x1.
11:35:33: Finished parsing scripts for resource group Essential
11:35:33: Creating resources for group Essential
11:35:33: All done
11:35:33: Parsing scripts for resource group General
11:35:33: Finished parsing scripts for resource group General
11:35:33: Creating resources for group General
11:35:33: All done
11:35:33: Parsing scripts for resource group Internal
11:35:33: Finished parsing scripts for resource group Internal
11:35:33: Creating resources for group Internal
11:35:33: All done
11:35:33: Parsing scripts for resource group Popular
11:35:33: Parsing script deferred_post.program
11:35:33: Parsing script ShadowCaster.program
11:35:33: Parsing script GBuffer.program
11:35:33: Parsing script triplanarReference.program
11:35:34: Parsing script DualQuaternion.program
11:35:34: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource DualQuaternion.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
11:35:34: High-level program Ogre/DualQuaternionHardwareSkinningTwoWeightsCg encountered an error during loading and is thus not supported.
OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource DualQuaternion.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
11:35:34: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1709)
11:35:34: Compiler error: invalid parameters in DualQuaternion.program(14): setting of constant failed
11:35:34: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource DualQuaternion.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
11:35:34: High-level program Ogre/DualQuaternionHardwareSkinningTwoWeightsTwoPhaseCg encountered an error during loading and is thus not supported.
OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource DualQuaternion.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
11:35:34: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1709)
11:35:34: Compiler error: invalid parameters in DualQuaternion.program(28): setting of constant failed
11:35:34: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource DualQuaternion_Common.glsl in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
11:35:39: DefaultWorkQueue('Root') shutting down on thread efc.
11:35:39: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread fb0 stopped.
11:35:39: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread 92c stopped.
11:35:39: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread e20 stopped.
11:35:39: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread 244 stopped.
11:35:39: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread 1354 stopped.
11:35:39: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread 9fc stopped.
11:35:39: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread de8 stopped.
11:35:39: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread 288 stopped.
11:35:39: Unregistering ResourceManager for type BspLevel
11:35:39: *-*-* OGRE Shutdown
11:35:39: Unregistering ResourceManager for type Compositor
11:35:39: Unregistering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
11:35:39: Unregistering ResourceManager for type Mesh
11:35:39: Unregistering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
11:35:39: Uninstalling plugin: Octree Scene Manager
11:35:39: Plugin successfully uninstalled
11:35:39: Unloading library .\Plugin_OctreeSceneManager_d
11:35:39: Uninstalling plugin: Cg Program Manager
11:35:39: Plugin successfully uninstalled
11:35:39: Unloading library .\Plugin_CgProgramManager_d
11:35:39: Uninstalling plugin: BSP Scene Manager
11:35:39: Plugin successfully uninstalled
11:35:39: Unloading library .\Plugin_BSPSceneManager_d
11:35:39: Uninstalling plugin: ParticleFX
11:35:39: Plugin successfully uninstalled
11:35:39: Unloading library .\Plugin_ParticleFX_d
11:35:39: Uninstalling plugin: GL RenderSystem
11:35:39: Unregistering ResourceManager for type GpuProgram
11:35:39: *** Stopping Win32GL Subsystem ***
11:35:39: Unregistering ResourceManager for type Texture
11:35:39: Plugin successfully uninstalled
11:35:39: Unloading library .\RenderSystem_GL_d
11:35:39: Unregistering ResourceManager for type Material
```

Comment: The `Ogre.log` log file would probably help a lot. And why can you only use the OpenGL render system? What happens if you try to use D3D9 for example?

Comment: In case I try to load D3D9, I have the following error message: Could not load .\RenderSystem_Direct3D9_d. Teh specified procedure could not be found in DynLib::load at ... OgreDynLib.cpp.

Comment: I edited also the question adding the ogre.log file for the case with the two resources not loading (scripts and materials). Thanks for your remarks.

Comment: Try to run just .exe file, instead of running it from IDE, it often helped me to understand resources errors. Do you have your 'DualQuaternion.cg' in correct place? Do you have DX SDK installed?

Comment: Hi, the DualQuaternion.cg is only located at `C:\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0\media\materials\programs\Cg`, which seems maybe not to be the right place? And for the directX development kit, I thought it was only necessary to add the correct dll in the folder of execution, but you suggest to install the whole DX sdk in order to be able to use this render system? thanks for your time

Comment: I managed to turn arround the problem, by using an older version of Ogre (v1.8.1), but this does not really resolve the question I guess.

Comment: Switching the version should not make any difference. Did you check that you have the material file and textures for the Ogre head in your paths listed in `resources.cfg`? If they are, there should be a matching log file entry telling you that they were loaded plus any potential errors.

Comment: Hi @PhilipAllgaier, I can't get the difference I have between the two different projects I have, one with Ogre 1.8.1 (working) and one with Ogre 1.9.0 (not working). As you said, I also believe it is not a question of versions, but then I am uncapable to find the tweak. Thanks anyway!